# Probability to win a solo card game

Tags: probability, card-games

I discovered a simple game with cards:

You have a [deck of 52 French Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck), this deck has four sets of cards with values from 1 to 10 and J Q K (which values are 11, 12, 13 respectively)

The game is very simple: you reveal the first card and say ONE, reveal the second card and say TWO and so on... After saying THIRTHEEN you restart the *voice counting*

If the revealed card value is the same as the said number, you have lost. If you finish the deck you have win.

Now comes my question: how can I compute manually the probability of winning to this game? (I already computed with programming so I simply want to know how to compute this probability by hand :) )

Here I attach some example of games:

Drawed cards:
2 4 6 8 **5**... -> lost because of 5 is the fifth card

4 **2**... -> lost because of 2 is the second card

13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 2 **1** -> lost because 1 is the 14th card (but after 13 we have to restart the count, so 1 correspond to saying ONE)

I hope that some of you can answer to my question :)

Comment: This is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) problem.

Comment: Who will play a  game with astronomical odds ?

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig, but as I see, the problem is a little more complex to define, since for each initial position of a card, I have four forbidden positions; have I to generalize the problem following the Generalizations section on Wikipedia?

Comment: @trueblueanil me an my friends tried to beat the game during an entire day, we won only once but it was funny  :)

Comment: @trueblueanil The probability of success is approximately $e^{-4}\approx0.0183$ so the odds are about $56:1$ against.  Not what I'd call astronomical.

Comment: You want to Google "rook polynomials".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This same problem occurred to me when I was an undergraduate, $50$-odd years ago.  I wasn't able to solve it it, though I thought about it off and on for about $15$ years.  Then I ran across rook polynomials, and was surprised how easy it was.

There's a good article on rook polynomials [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial#Complete_boards).

In actually doing the problem, it's easier if you think about calling the cards in the order $1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,...$ which obviously doesn't change the probability of success.  Then the dark chessboard of forbidden positions consists of $13$ $4\times4$ chessboards, arranged in block diagonal fashion.  Since the rook polynomial of a  $4\times4$ board is $$24x^4+96x^3+72x^2+16x+1,$$ (see the wiki article,) the rook polynomial of the entire dark chessboard is  $$\left(24x^4+96x^3+72x^2+16x+1\right)^{13}$$

Then just apply the formula.

If we have $s$ suits and $r$ ranks (so in the question $s=4, r=13$) then as $s$ remains fixed and $r\to\infty$ one can show that the probability of success approaches $e^{-s}$.  This is the basis of my comment that the probability is approximately $e^{-4},$ though frankly, I can't remember how good that approximation is when $r=13$.  I seem to remember that it came out to be about $1/60$, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Note that when $s=1$, this is just the problem of derangements, and it's well-known that the probability of success approaches $e^{-1}$.

**EDIT**

One other thing I'd like to mention is that friends I showed the problem to often answered $$\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^{52},$$ incorrectly treating the events as independent, but this doesn't give a bad first approximation, since
$$\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^{52}=\left(\left(1-\frac1{13}\right)^{13}\right)^4\approx e^{-4}$$

**EDIT**

Couldn't resist it.  I wrote this python script

```
from sympy import Symbol, factorial

x = Symbol('x')
p = 24*x**4+96*x**3+72*x**2+16*x+1
c = (p**13).as_poly().coeffs()[::-1]
n = sum((-1)**k*c[k]*factorial(52-k) for k in range(53))

prob = n/factorial(52)
```

The probability of success is

$$\frac{4610507544750288132457667562311567997623087869}{284025438982318025793544200005777916187500000000}\\\approx0.016232727467194636$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1) I was too quick on the draw !